# update more than one result in same uri

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I want to update the same result document to accumulate all the meta elements. I have tried to recreate the multiple dita-ot templates to explain the problem here. My question is, is it possible to update keyword.xml in the

```
<xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">
```

template itself? maybe using xsl:stream or xsl:accumulator? XSLT 3 and Saxon-HE-9.8.0-12

Input XML

```
<root>
<article>
<html name="firsthtm">
    <head>Head1</head>
    <meta>keyword;firsthtm</meta>
</html>
<html name="secondhtm">
    <head>Head2</head>
    <meta>keyword;secondhtm</meta>
</html>
<html name="thirdhtm">
    <head>Head3</head>
    <meta>keyword;thirdhtm</meta>
</html>
</article>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="pages"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">
    <xsl:result-document href="{@name}.html">
        <html>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </title>
        </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <!-- update keyword.xml for each html  -->
    <xsl:result-document href="keyword.xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="meta"/>
        </root>      
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

```
 firsthtm.htm
 <html>
     <title>firsthtm</title>
 </html>

 secondhtm.htm
 <html>
     <title>secondhtm</title>
 </html>

 thirdhtm.htm
 <html>
     <title>thirdhtm</title>
 </html>

 keyword.xml
 <root>
     <meta>keyword;secondhtm</meta>
     <meta>keyword;secondhtm</meta>
     <meta>keyword;thridhtm</meta>
 </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the result document in the template matching `article`:

```
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="pages"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="keyword.xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="html/meta"/>
        </root>      
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to use the `match="html" mode="pages"` then you have to decide on which match you want to construct that result e.g on the first

```
<xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">
    <xsl:result-document href="{@name}.html">
        <html>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </title>
        </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <!-- update keyword.xml for first html  -->
    <xsl:variable name="html-index" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$html-index = 1">
      <xsl:result-document href="keyword.xml">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::article/html/meta"/>
        </root>      
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

In simple cases (there are only those `html` element children for the `article` and you have used `xsl:strip-space`) it might suffice to simply test `<xsl:if test="position() = 1">`.

Comment: How to get the same result in <xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">? is it even possible?

Comment: @DitaNewbieLa, see the edit, you can only write to the same URI once so you have to pick one of the matched `html` elements to construct the result document and then select the `meta` elements.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be moving the `xsl:result-document` to the `article` template and copy all `html/meta` elements from there:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="article">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="pages"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="keyword.xml">
            <root>
                <xsl:copy-of select="html/meta"/>
            </root>            
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">
        <xsl:result-document href="{@name}.html">
            <html>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </title>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <!-- update keyword.xml for each html  -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the problem is, the code is part of the customized dita-ot web-help plugin and I have access to only <xsl:template match="html" mode="pages">.